# Crash on Particle Effects

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I try to add some particle effects at end of game. in device it worked fine. and in simulator it crashes. i attached the screenshot regarding crash.

it says getting image failed. My Particle str path is firework.plist 
in debug its shows correct path. 
but i got this error ***Get data from file(Images/FinishEffect/particleTexture.png) failed!***

why its taking wrong path

check screnshot here :- http://postimg.org/image/k97ql9z59/

My code:-

```
 CCParticleSystem *emitter;
            char particleStr[64];

            sprintf(particleStr,PARTICLE_EFFECT_FINISH_GAME_SCENE);

            emitter = CCParticleSystemQuad::create(particleStr);
            emitter->setScale(ScreenHelper::getTextureScale());

            emitter->setPosition(ccp((m_StartPos.x*PTM_RATIO+RandomInt(-100,100))*ScreenHelper::getCameraZoom(),(m_StartPos.y*PTM_RATIO+RandomInt(-50,150))*ScreenHelper::getCameraZoom()));  // setting emitter position
            m_ccLayer->getParent()->addChild(emitter,10); // adding the emitter
```

In this line crash occurs only in simulator.                 ***emitter = CCParticleSystemQuad::create(particleStr);***

Comment: You'll find that very few around here care to follow links posted by random strangers. Code, on the other hand, is appreciated.

Comment: @molbdnilo, added code in my question.... Plz check...

Comment: in image u can see in log window its taken some png image from inside "Firework.plist"  but in my code i given firework.plist path in "particlestr"

Comment: It's possible that only the simulator crashes on invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your `Firework.plist` file you will notice that it has `textureFileName`. It tells the particle engine which texture to use for your particles. Cocos requires this to work, because it doesn't "draw" the particles itself, it rather uses the provided texture and applies color to it - that's why it generally should be white, but color textures can be used to obtain different results.

Comment: but in device its coming fireworks... in simulator it crash.. why ?